# Xero Webhook Validation (Intent to Receive) - Response not 2XX

Tags: node.js, validation, webhooks, xero-api, pipedream

I'm trying to create a Xero webhook and connect it up to Pipedream but I can't get the "Intent to receive" validation working properly. I've tried a couple of different approaches (using Node.js). This was my first attempt:

```
import crypto from "crypto";

export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {

    const key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          payload = steps.trigger.event.body.toString(),
          // payload = JSON.stringify({"events": [],"lastEventSequence": 0,"firstEventSequence": 0,"entropy": "S0m3r4Nd0mt3xt"}),
          calculatedHmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(payload).digest('base64'),
          xeroSignature = steps.trigger.event.headers["x-xero-signature"];

        // console.log(calculatedHmac.trim());
        // console.log(xeroSignature);

    if (calculatedHmac.trim() === xeroSignature) {
      await $.respond({
        status: 200,
        headers: {},
        body: 'ok',
      })
    } else {
      await $.respond({
        status: 401,
        headers: {},
        body: 'unauthorised',
      })
    }
  },
})
```

And this was my second attempt based on an old GitHub repo I found:

```
export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {

    const { createHmac } = await import('crypto');
    const xero_webhook_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    const body_string = JSON.stringify(steps.trigger.event.body)
    const xero_hash = steps.trigger.event.headers["x-xero-signature"]

    let our_hash = createHmac('sha256', xero_webhook_key).update(body_string).digest("base64") // Generate the hash Xero wants
    let statusCode = xero_hash == our_hash ? 200 : 401 // If the hashes match, send a 200, else send a 401

    await $.respond({
      status: statusCode
    });

  }
})
```

Both methods are returning `401` every time, even when a correctly signed signature is sent from Xero. In the first lot of code you'll see I've used `console.log` to show the calculated HMAC and the Xero Signature, but they never match.

Based on some other threads I found I've also tried using `.toString()` rather than `JSON.stringify()`, and tried hardcoding an example payload but none of that worked either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow for raw body request type in your API.

This is how I did it using Nest JS:

```
    //main.ts
     const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {rawBody: true});
    
    //webhook.controller.ts
     @Post()
     async xeroWebhookController (
        @Req() req: RawBodyRequest<Request>,
        @Res() res: Response
      ) {

    const rawPayload = query.rawBody.toString()
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', this.config.xeroHashKey).update(rawPayload).digest('base64');
    }
```

and just regular Express JS

```
//app.ts
//middleware
this.express.use("/api/3/xero-integrations/xeroWebhook", bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json', limit: '50mb' }), xeroWebhookController)

//xeroWebhook.controllers.ts
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', process.env.XERO_HASH_KEY).update(req.body.toString()).digest('base64');
```